# ASP.Net Binding Multiple Models

Tags: asp.net, string, http-post

**Objective:**

In the project I'm working **I would like to save information in paralel of two defined models: `Machine` and `Devices`.**

The relation between them is that the `Machine` has a collection of `Devices`.

The user will save information of the new Machine and indicate how many Devices this Machine has.

**For this reason**, I would like to save as many devices as the user says this particular machine has in the `Device` model.

**Code: Saving Machine info and Devices info**

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateEditPost(int? id,
        [Bind("TypeID,BrandID,SupplierID,StoreID,MchName,NumDevices,FechaCompra,CostoMaq,MachineStatus")]Machine model,
        [Bind("Id,DeviceName")]Device devicemodel)
     {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (id == 0)
            {
                _context.Add(model);
                //loop thru the number of devices the user wrote
                //for each one, add a new item in the Device model
                //what will differentiate them is the DeviceName
                for (var items = 0; items < model.NumDevices; items++)
                {
                   //Question 1: Getting an error trying to construct this var
                    string devicename = new string(model.MchName, items.ToString);
                    devicemodel.DeviceName = devicename;
                   //Question 2: I should validate the model is valid 
                   _context.Add(devicemodel);
                }
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
       }
       return RedirectToAction("Index");
     }
```

**Question: About ModelState.IsValid**
This, at the moment, is validating that the Machine model is valid. I would need to validate that the Device model is valid too, how can I differentiate them?

```
                for (var items = 0; items < model.NumDevices; items++)
                {
                    string devicename = new string(model.MchName, items.ToString);
                    devicemodel.DeviceName = devicename;
                   if(ModelState.IsValid)
                   { 
                      _context.Add(devicemodel);
                   }
                }
```

Will this be enough?

**Question: About looping thru the NumDevices property in order to save the devices**

This line:

```
string devicename = new string(model.MchName, items.ToString);
```

Is not correct.

I'm getting an error on each argument:
model.MchName -> cannot convert string to char
items.ToString -> cannot converte from 'method groups' to 'int'

For this, MchName is defined as a string in the `Machine` model.

I thank for any feedback before hand.

Regards